# How to calculate contract fraction of the year by percent?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Team,

I'm trying to get a waterfall of financials by year. I need to find a percentage of what contracts were valid within the contract end year, by year, before pulling in financials. I have the contract start and end dates as the source data points to pull over the % of the contract in that year.

I get the 'syntax is incorrect' using this formula in dax':

```
Z - 2020 % = IF(OR('Sales Force_Contract'[StartDate]>=NEXTYEAR(),'Sales
 Force_Contract'[EndDate]<STARTOFYEAR()),MIN('Sales
 Force_Contract'[EndDate],NEXTYEAR())-MAX('Sales
 Force_Contract'[StartDate],STARTOFYEAR()))))
```

Or this formula (test 2):

```
Z - 2020 %% = 
IF (
    NEXTYEAR('Sales Force_Contract'[StartDate]>="2021")) ||
    STARTOFYEAR('Sales Force_Contract'[EndDate]<="2020")),
    "0" ,min('Sales Force_Contract'[EndDate],nextyear()(-max('Sales Force_Contract'[StartDate],NEXTYEAR))))
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: in first formula you have more close braces than required

Comment: Siva  - Can you confirm where the extra brackets are? I removed a few, and now am getting 'too frew arguments were passed'? I copied your edit, and received an error. Thoughts? Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: I copied your first formula in notepad++ and found last 2 closing braces doesn't have any matching opening braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using NEXTYEAR and STARTOFYEAR are not right. Look up the functions you are using in the Microsoft documentation to see examples. For example, [NEXTYEAR( )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/nextyear-function-dax) needs a column of dates and returns a table of dates. Because it returns a table, it is usually used as a filter in a CALCULATE statement. Here is an example of using NEXTYEAR in a CALCULATE statement:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(InternetSales_USD[SalesAmount_USD]), NEXTYEAR('DateTime'[DateKey]))
```

If you want more help writing the formula, paste in a table of sample data for StartDate and EndDate. For example, are they both always filled in? Is EndDate sometimes empty? Also include an expected result. If a contract spans multiple years, how should that be counted?